# JavaCC - Missing Return Statement Exception

Tags: java, javacc

In the generated parser file, this method throws a missing return statement exception, although I find the return statement is always reachable. Here is the function:

```
Program Goal():
{
  MainClass mc;
  ClassDecl cd;
  ClassDeclList cdl = new ClassDeclList();
}
{
  mc = mainClass()
   (
     cd = ClassDeclaration()
     {
       cdl.addElement(cd);  
     }
   )* < EOF >
   {
     return new Program(mc, cdl);
   }
}
```

Thanks.

**EDIT**

So, the problem wasn't in this method, but in another method. In brief, the issue was that in that method, I had some ORs , and a java return statement at the end. [I should have surrounded all the ORed function calls by a pair of parenthesis](https://java.net/projects/javacc/lists/users/archive/2004-08/message/37), but I missed that.

The following is what I should have done.

```
Exp expression() :
{
  Token t;
  Exp exp = null;
  IntegerLiteral il;
  FloatLiteral fl;
  CharLiteral cl;
  StringLiteral sl;
  String s;
  Identifier id;
  Exp tmpExp = null;
}
{
  ( // <--- This and its enclosing parenthesis are what I missed.
    (
      t = < INTEGRAL_LITERAL >
      {
        il = new IntegerLiteral(Integer.parseInt(t.image));
      }
      exp = ExpressionBar(il)
    )
  |
    (
      t = < FLOAT_LITERAL >
      {
        fl = new FloatLiteral(Float.parseFloat(t.image));
      }
      exp = ExpressionBar(fl)
    )
  |
    (
      t = < CHAR_LITERAL >
      {
        cl = new CharLiteral(t.image.charAt(1));
      }
      exp = ExpressionBar(cl)
    )
  |
    (
      t = < STRING_LITERAL >
      {
        sl = new StringLiteral(t.image);
      }
      exp = ExpressionBar(sl)
    )
  )
  {
    return exp;
  }
}
```

Comment: Is the exception actually thrown when you execute the method?

Comment: @TheodoreNorvell
Yes.

Comment: I can not reproduce the problem. I copied and pasted the above definition and ran it through JavaCC 5.  The output java for method Goal ends with `{if (true) return new Program(mc, cdl);} throw new Error("Missing return statement in function");`. Although this looks odd, the throw clearly can not be reached. This is the only throw in the method.

Comment: Thank you for caring :) . Although there is a generated throw, it's not thrown when the method is executed. The problem was in another method. Shamefully, I poorly traced the error then, but now everything is fine. I am linking the solution to my problem in the edit.

Thanks.